# PotPlayer does not play sound when playing 'next' file

Tags: windows-11, daum-pot-player

When I start PotPlayer it can play ONLY the first file with sound and after it starts playing the next file in the playlist it plays it without sound. Everything with the files is ok, it plays them perfectly if I restart PotPlayer.
Sound dissapears even if I replace the currectly played file using PotPlayer -> Open file(s)...
Tried restarting PC, reinstalling PotPlayer but the problem persists. It's annoying to have to restart the player for every file.

Edit: I found out it works ok if I select Audio -> Audio Renderer -> Default WaveOut Device. But it does not want to work with 'Default DirectSound Device' - it plays sound only for the first file. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: What version of PotPlayer are you using? Have you reinstalled? Drivers updated?

Comment: @music2myear Version: 220706(1.7.21765).
Yes, I've reinstalled several times.
Yes, drivers are updated.

Comment: Btw, I found out it works ok if I select Audio -> Audio Renderer -> Default WaveOut Device. But it does not want to work with 'Default DirectSound Device' - it plays sound only for the first file.

Comment: Add that information to the question please. Use the EDIT button. This makes your question more complete and clear, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for v230523 for me too. I had to restart the app too. (Side note: also, the actual "Preferences" window has suddenly become very hard to find.)